# Laravel admin image cant access via url

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-admin

I have create an app that need to upload image.

I use http://laravel-admin.org/

already setup all and follow the documentation. All work, but my image cannot access via url

its said `404 - Not Found`

[image]

when access via url.

[image]

checked on explorer its already there.

[image]

here my `config/filesystems.php`

```
....
'disks' => [

    'local' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app'),
    ],

    'public' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
        'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
        'visibility' => 'public',
    ],

    'admin' => [
      'driver' => 'local',
      'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
      'visibility' => 'public',
      'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
    ],
....
```

here my `config/admin.php`

```
....
'upload' => [
    'disk' => 'admin',
    'directory' => [
        'image' => 'images',
        'file'  => 'files',
    ],
    'host' => 'http://localhost:8000/upload/',
],
....
```

any can help and explain, got stuck about 3 hours :')

Comment: did you make the symlink for the public disk ?

Comment: already did, with `php artisan storage:link`

Comment: I guess, you should try "/storage/images/" and then your image name stored in the database to show your image, if you have already done storage:link.

Comment: @Shreeraj already did it, still not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ref your explorer screen, so the image is stored in `public disk`/`images`

the easy way is access it by `Storage::disk('public')->url('images/'. $image);`

if you want create another disk, i can post more code

also you can use Accessor, in your model add this

```
public function getShowImageAttribute()
{
    return \Storage::disk('public')->url('images/'. $this->attributes['image_column_name_here']);
}
```

so you can access it in the blade like this

```
{{ $user->show_image }}
```

Comment: what you mean ? you want hard coded the link in blade ? what about in some day you want change the path name, you need change all source code ....

Comment: wtf i just change `http://localhost` to `http://127.0.0.1:8000` and now its working. can you explain why thats different?...

Comment: ah i know, 80 and 8000 not a same, sad.